# Assign absolute path to single layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, file-path

Under Project Properties, I set path savings to 'relative', as the project is used by different people and moved between network drives. Shapefiles that move with the project are correctly located in this way.

For some shapefiles, I would like to assign an absolute path, as they are saved on a specific location and won't be moved with the project itself.

Is there a way to assign an absolute path to one specific shapefile in QGIS?

Comment: try to move to a central database rather than network drives and shapefiles - that is almost certainly going to end with corrupted data

Comment: Or implement a best practice where everyone uses the same place on their network drive to store the project, so the relative path to that one file is the same for everyone.